# How to convert the data for Weka

Tags: macos, text-files, weka

I'm using MAC, and I'm new to Weka.

Now I need to download the data from this URL: http://fimi.ua.ac.be/data/T10I4D100K.dat

Then use Weka to analysis the data. However, I tried to save the data as .txt or copy paste it in MAC Text Edit then save as .dat file, Weka cannot recognize it.

I have tried to open the data in Weka through the URL but also failed. It shows couldn't read URL...

I have tried to download the file as .txt and read each line into .dat file by using Java...

All failed. Weka always shows "Unable to determine structure as svm light"

Does anyone know what can I do?

Comment: Try typing the following into Terminal... `curl http://fimi.ua.ac.be/data/T10I4D100K.dat > ~/Desktop/T10I4D100K.dat` and then opening the new file that appears on your Desktop in Weka.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you Mark, just tried it, Weka still shows "unable to determine structure as svm light"....

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the Java code and change the downloaded data into .arff format, then Weka can read it.